# Are UK accounting laws compatible with South African accounting laws?

Tags: united-kingdom, south-africa

My mother is in South Africa. She has British Passport and would like to return to the UK.

At present, she is a bookkeeper in South Africa but as I understand it, different countries have different laws (financial/bookkeeping).

Would she be able to come to the UK and work without having to complete some training to be able to practice?

Comment: Are you asking about bookkeeping or accounting?  Bookkeeping is generally not a regulated undertaking because it doesn't involve things like preparing financial reports for regulated entities.  Accounting may be regulated particularly if you need a CPA.

Comment: @JustinCave I am talking about bookkeeping. Apologies for the confusion; I have amended my question.

Comment: I don't think this question is off-topic here, but I'm not sure this is the best site for it either. Perhaps this would be better at the [Finance SE](http://quant.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Book keeping is pretty much generic wherever you go I would think, it's just keeping the financial records of a company. To be recognised as an accountant though requires you to pass an examination to get certified in that particular country unless they recognise another countries certifications. And in some countries you have to resit the exam periodically.

Book keeping (as far as I know) really just means financial data entry, which anyone can do and doesn't require qualifications. Accounting goes a lot further into the realm of adjusting data and more.

So while I do the book keeping for my work, the accounting is done by an accountant, although there is a fair bit of overlap since we're both using the same software.

In answer to the question, your mother should be fine to go and work as a book keeper in the UK.